# The type or namespace name 'IObservable' could not be found. Are you missing a using or directive or assembly reference?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm attempting to implement the IObservable interface in C# using Mono 2.10.6, and Monodevelop 2.8.2, and I keep getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'IObservable' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using or directive or assembly reference?

I'm using:

- System
- System.Collections.Generic;
- System.Collections.ObjectModel

I have references to:

- System
- System.Core

Comment: What framework version are you targeting? `IObservable` is new to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have to compile for .NET 4.0:

```
#if NET_4_0

namespace System{
  public interface IObservable<out T>
  {
    IDisposable Subscribe (IObserver<T> observer);
  }
}

#endif
```

(Taken from [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System/System/IObservable.cs.htm)).

Maybe you have not set to .NET 4.0 as the target framework?